# When reading bytes from a file, reads it like a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I'm reading bytes from file using
`open("file.txt", "rb"")` python adds brackets in the beginning and end of the bytes, like list.

I've tried to manually cut the brackets using `re.sub` but because it is a list, I got an error code saying `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` since it's a list.
(The reason I used `f.readlines(0)` below instead of just normal file reading is because I store other variables on this file)

```
>>> foo = os.urandom("128")
>>> print(foo) 
b'\xb9\xfe\xeb\x03e\xe8\x8e\x0c\xc1\x05\xb1\xe8\xadB\x9d\xdf_-\xd2\x8c\x18\xe2\xb2\xc7\xf9I\x18\xa7(\xefe\xc9\xc4:\xb3\x93\n+\x7f\x8e\xd2\x82\xf0!\x9668\x01\xcdf\x0f\x15\xe6r\xec\x01\xb8\x7f\x8d\xa25\xd6yq\x1e#\xfb\x0eY\x0fE\x1a)V\xb2\xcb_\x89yH\xd9\xf9\xc7.\x12\x98\x16\xe4!k\xdfU>\xa2\xf0H\xcbT3.\xbd\xbdn\x8aU<\xeb\xf7\xca\xd6~\xf2R\xca\x0f\x8f\x9d\xce\xd8D\xa6f,H\xf8\xcc\xca\x1f' 
>>> f = open("t.text", "wb") 
>>> f.write(foo)
>>> f.close() 
>>> f = open("t.text", "rb") 
>>> bar = f.readlines(0)
>>> print(bar)
[b'\xb9\xfe\xeb\x03e\xe8\x8e\x0c\xc1\x05\xb1\xe8\xadB\x9d\xdf_-\xd2\x8c\x18\xe2\xb2\xc7\xf9I\x18\xa7(\xefe\xc9\xc4:\xb3\x93\n', b'+\x7f\x8e\xd2\x82\xf0!\x9668\x01\xcdf\x0f\x15\xe6r\xec\x01\xb8\x7f\x8d\xa25\xd6yq\x1e#\xfb\x0eY\x0fE\x1a)V\xb2\xcb_\x89yH\xd9\xf9\xc7.\x12\x98\x16\xe4!k\xdfU>\xa2\xf0H\xcbT3.\xbd\xbdn\x8aU<\xeb\xf7\xca\xd6~\xf2R\xca\x0f\x8f\x9d\xce\xd8D\xa6f,H\xf8\xcc\xca\x1f\xcc\x96\xaa\x9d\xc5\xebE\xc8\x0b\xe6G"\xb9\xf1T\x80']
```

How can I read it as bytes instead of list?
(I store other bytes on different lines, this on line 1 and another on line 2. I can't store them on different files).

EDIT: The solution is this: f.read(data_size).

Comment: to read the contents full just do `f.read()`, for just one line do `next(f)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre as I said, every line is a different variable, and therefore i can't just do f.read().

Comment: `f.readlines` returns a list. You can't make it return anything else than a list. You can, however, retrieve elements of this list. (You do realize that the brackets denote a list, right?)

Comment: It's a bit odd to want to read a binary file line by line. If it has lines, isn't it text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo = f.readlines(0)
```

this is just reading all file lines as a list, with a size hint of zero (not very useful)

You want to read the first line just do:

```
foo = next(f)
```

note that if your data is binary, the notion of "line" won't help much, since if there's a linefeed char in your data, it will be seen as the end of a line.

Here it *will* happen, as the data you're writing is random. So consider storing the data as json or base64 encoded to make sure that a linefeed character doesn't get in the way (and it does, look at the full data you've read, it has 2 lines)

Or make note of the size of the data and use `f.read(data_size)`. Knowning the size is the only way with binary streams.

Comment: Now I'm just getting a part of it.
```b'\xb9\xfe\xeb\x03e\xe8\x8e\x0c\xc1\x05\xb1\xe8\xadB\x9d\xdf_-\xd2\x8c\x18\xe2\xb2\xc7\xf9I\x18\xa7(\xefe\xc9\xc4:\xb3\x93\n'``` instead of the full bytes.